# Не получается обратить к вышестоящему элементу с помощью this

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть набор продуктовых секций `product-section`. По кнопке `+` конкретной секции необходимо получить цену `amount`, чтобы в дальнейшем с ней работать. Но у меня не получается обратиться к вышестоящему полю `quantity` через `this`. Как это можно сделать?

```js
$('.product-section .product-quantity .plus').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var quantity = $this.find(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
   var basePrice = "";
   for (var i = 1; i < quantity.length; i++) {
     basePrice += quantity[i];
   }
   console.log(basePrice);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-section">
  <table class="description-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="product-quantity">
          <div class="quantity buttons_added">
            <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
            <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
            <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: А просто по #num_count обратиться к элементу нельзя?

Comment: @Visman нет, нельзя - в этом наборе секций все элементы с `id="num_count"`

Comment: id элементов должны быть уникальными.

Comment: @Visman теоретически да, но на практике не всегда так - спросите у wordpress ))

Comment: Незнание законов не освобождает от ответственности. P.S. Делайте так как правильно, а не так как WP пошлет.

Comment: @Visman в смысле правильно? вордспрес самостоятельно без моего участия так классы и дивы назначает- мы лишь можем работать с тем, что имеем. и закон этот я прекрасно знаю - с чего вы вдруг решили, что нет?

Comment: Вероятно шаблон написан неправильно. Для примера в content.php id статьи формируется так <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" ...,то есть у WP есть возможность для каждого блока формировать уникальные id элементов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пройтись по дереву родителей, указав нужный элемент в котором находится input. Потом в нем уже найти требуемый input.

```
$('.product-section .product-quantity .plus').click(function() {
      var $input_amount = $(this).parents('.quantity ').find('input[name="quantity"]');
     $input_amount.val(parseInt($input_amount.val(),10)+1);
     alert($input_amount.val());        
    });
```

Comment: да, @Vitaliy Shevchenko спасибо, но решил проще - через свойство `change` текстового поля

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('.quantity').find(...);
```